# merge two regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I have two regular expressions, one pulling out usernames from a csv string, and the other pulling out emails.

the string format is like this:

```
String s = "name lastname (username) <mail@mail.something.dk>; name lastname (username) <mail@mail.something.dk>; name lastname (username) <mail@mail.something.dk>";
```

the code for my regular expressions are like this.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()[^\\)]+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
Pattern pattern2 = Pattern.compile("((?<=<)[^>]+)");
Matcher matcher2 = pattern2.matcher(s);

while (matcher.find() && matcher2.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group() + " " + matcher2.group());
}
```

I've found several qeustions about merging regexes, but from the answers i haven't been able to figure out how to merge mine.

my printouts show:

```
"username mail@mail.com"
```

would I be able to **print out the same** from a **single matcher**, using one regex?

obs: this is a school assignment, which means i do not "need" to merge them or do any more, but i'd like to know if it is possible, and how difficult it would be.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can just use an `Pipe (|)` in between your `multiple Regex`, to match all of them : -

```
    String s = "name lastname (username) <mail@mail.something.dk>; name lastname
            (username) <mail@mail.something.dk>; name lastname 
            (username) <mail@mail.something.dk>;";

    // Matches (?<=\\()[^\\)]+  or  ((?<=<)[^>]+)
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\()[^\\)]+|((?<=<)[^>]+)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
username
mail@mail.something.dk
username
mail@mail.something.dk
username
mail@mail.something.dk
```

**UPDATE**: -

If you want to print `username` and `email` only when they both exists, then you need to split your string on `;` and then apply the below Regex on each of them.

Here's the code: -

```
    String s = "name lastname (username) ; 
                name lastname (username) <mail@mail.something.dk>; 
                name lastname (username) <mail@mail.something.dk>;";

    String [] strArr = s.split(";");

    for (String str: strArr) {

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\)]+)(?:\\))\\s(?:\\<)((?<=<)[^>]+)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.print(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

**OUTPUT**: -

```
username mail@mail.something.dk
username mail@mail.something.dk // Only the last two have both username and email
```

Comment: I guess OP wants to AND regexps, not OR them

Comment: @AdamDyga No he wants both username and email from the single regex..  See : - `would i be able to print out the same from a single matcher, using one regex?`

Comment: there is small difference, OPs code (`(matcher.find() && matcher2.find())` requires that both username and mail must be in the string in order to be printed.

Comment: @AdamDyga. This can also be done.. just need to replace `println` with `print`. That will do exactly what OP's regex does.

Comment: not really, it's not a matter of displaying but logical condition, OP's condition requires that both username AND email must be in the input string, otherwise NOTHING is displayed. Your code doesn't work like that.

Comment: @AdamDyga. I see. I'll check how I can modify the regex for that.

Comment: @AdamDyga. Updated code. Now it does what you said. And what probably OP wants.

Comment: that's closer ;) Normally it will work fine in this case but is still not 100% equivalent of OP's code (your code requires that username comes always first). But OK, I'm caviling too much now...

Comment: @AdamDyga. OOPs..Then is there any way out? I don't have much experience in Regex. So, don't know about some tricky way.

Comment: @AdamDyga OP's format clearly shows that username always comes first

Comment: @RohitJain yeah, the truth is that it not easy to do with one regexp. The only solution that comes to my mind is to use the fact that logically A AND B = NOT( NOT(A) OR NOT(B) ). Not sure if it's doable with regexp but it will definitely produce an ugly expression

Comment: @AdamDyga. OK. But yeah a Regex is always a String specific. For different string, it is built differently. So a Regex has not to work in all cases. It should work for the particular case it was built for. Thanks :)

Comment: @AdamDyga. That would be a disaster, if you want that in Regex. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The following code will extract your pairs. The regex is quite short, but I am almost sure, there is a more elegant way (there always is with regex!). ;)

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "name1 lastname1 (user1); name2 lastname2 (username2) <mail2@mail.something.dk>; name3 lastname3 (username3) <mail3@mail.something.dk>;";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(([^\\)]+)\\)\\s<([^>]+)>");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1) + " " + matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

> username2 mail2@mail.something.dk
>   username3 mail3@mail.something.dk

Explanation for the regex `"\\(([^\\)]+)\\)\\s<([^>]+)>"`:

- `\\(([^\\)]+)\\)`: A group of non-`)` characters enclosed by `(` and `)`
- `\\s`: A space in between
- `<([^>]+)>`: A group of non-`>` characters enclosed by `<` and `>`