# Single RegEx to support both Email and Alphanumeric string

Tags: javascript, c#, regex

I am using the following 2 patterns

1 - To Test alphanumeric without space and with some special characters like '-','#','&'

```
var test =  /^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-#&\s]{6,})*$/

A - test.test('Kumar'); // False (Since 6 characters are not there)

B - test.test('Bibek1211');//True

C - test.test('Bibek1211#-&');//True

D - test.test('Bibek12 Kumar');//False (Since space is there)
```

2 - To Test Email

```
 var test =  /^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])?$/
```

Now i got a requirement to merge the above two regEx and put it in one regex.This is where i am facing issues since i have very few knowledge in regex.

I want to add the above 2 regex and put it in one single regex (Both in c# and javascript)so that one single regex can able to validate the following pattern

```
A - test.test('Kumar'); // False (Since 6 characters are not there)
B - test.test('Bibek1211');//True
C - test.test('Bibek1211#-&');//True
D - test.test('Bibek12 Kumar');//False (Since space is there)
E - test.test('Kumar@gmail.com');//True
F - test.test('Kumar@gmailcom');//False (Not an Email)
```

Please help me to get the above . Thanks in advance !!

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858116/merge-two-regular-expressions

Comment: @Oceans pipe concept is there for java . Is it applicable for c# and javascript too ?

Comment: Regular expressions are regular expressions, so the same can be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply club the 2 regexes using `|` or `or`.

```
^(?:(?:[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])?)|([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-#&]{6,}))$
```

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/iJ3dS6/1

Comment: Can we do the same in  ASP.Net MVC model using for unobtrusive validation .

Answer (score 1):

What about below code

```
^[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[A-Za-z0-9](?:[A-Za-z0-9-]*[A-Za-z0-9])?\.)+[A-Za-z](?:[A-Za-z]*[A-Za-z])?$ |^([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-#&\s]{6,})*$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

this may be the original pic : https://www.debuggex.com/i/tK73IHD4OYz9mWAR.png