# How to do String comparison of look alike words, using Regular expressions in Java?

Tags: java, regex

I have two String

```
String x = "DMXX"; //or DMYY or DMZZ
```

I want to check equality.

Earlier i was doing it like

```
if(x.equals("DMXX") || x.equals("DMYY") || x.equals("DMZZ")){
  //Do this and that
}
```

Instead of three different statements; i want to do it in one.

In above string 'DM' will be common for all; only change will be XX/YY/ZZ.

What will be syntax for regular expressions to make it one statement instead of two?

Also, additional query: Do Guava or Apache Commons have some functionality to achieve same?

Comment: `x.matches("DD(?:XX|YY|ZZ)")`. You can pull the `Pattern` out and reuse it for speed. You can also reuse the `Matcher` for speed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12858116/merge-two-regular-expressions says: put a pipe between them.

Comment: You have turned your question from a perfectly reasonable one to an unclear one with the addition of a single like. What do you expect Guava or Apache Commons to bring to the party? Given this is literally a single method call in the Java API?

Comment: @BoristheSpider: In coding standards, which already followed in project, they even do not use string.equals and instead use StringUtils.equals. So that was just addon query. Also reverted the question.

Comment: How is `equals` or `StringUtils.equals` in any way related to regex, might I ask?

Comment: That, i gave you an example that project rely more on third party tools for String handling then first party.

Comment: I might add the `StringUtils.equals` is identical to `Objects.equals` from the JDK. Having a requirement to use third party functionality that has been **long** superseded by JDK functionality is simply wrong - I would suggest a frank discussion needs to be had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (x.matches("DM(?:XX|YY|ZZ)") {
    // Do whatever
}
```

Edit 1: You can of course change the characters `DM`, `XX`, `YY` and `ZZ` to whatever you need and note that `XX` and friends do not have to be the same length. For instance with `DM1234` and `DM2`, the regex `"DM(?:1234|2|ZZ)"` will work just fine.

Edit 2-3: As  Sebastian Proske and Boris the Spider commented and unlike what a tutorial led me to believe, `String.matches` does match the regular expression as if it had anchors (as if it already started with a `^` and ended with a `$`) so those are not required. That will teach me to read tutorials and not double check. ^^

Comment: Can we do it using StringUtils of Apache commons or any other Gauva Library?

Comment: Please do add add code only as answer. Add a description too

Comment: @fatherazrael what do you seek to gain from external libraries over literally one method call?

Comment: What would be the point of using StringUtils when the `matches` method is provided in pure Java and does what you need?

Comment: Actually in coding standards we are not suppose to do equality check using string.equlas() and rely on StringUtils :(

Comment: @NadiaCerezo you should ping the person whose comment you are replying to with an `@`; just be sure they notice.

Comment: If you're going to impose very odd requirements (*only* using specific third-party libraries, nothing in `java.lang.String`) those requirements should really be in the question, otherwise we're playing a guessing game. That's a really bizarre requirement, too...

Comment: @fatherazrael The solution I gave you does not use `String.equals`... are you sure it is incorrect by your coding standards?

Comment: @fatherazrael you coding standards suck. The Guava team themselves say to prefer the JDK functionality when available.

Comment: @Boris

It is not mine coding standards. It is project standards which imposed on us. It is easy to use equals and matches for me, as i have learned this only ;)

Comment: Thanks. It is working fine. Accepted this as answer.

Comment: @fatherazrael Still, it seems extremely weird to me that you would try to use something other than `String.matches` when it is clearly the best tool for the job... Can you check with someone more familiar with the coding standards? Because, they might be unclear or in need of fixing. ^^

Comment: Sure. This standard is even weird for me. But when top management say follow, we juniors simply follow. :) Thanks Answer accepted.

Comment: @Nadia When using `.matches()` you don't need start and end anchors, as it always checks the whole string.

Comment: You answer was correct before you added the anchors - I'm going to have to revoke my vote.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I disagree. Remember the OP said they wanted to check equality. Matching the string without the anchors will clearly not be equivalent to a call to `equals()` and that is what the OP asked for.

Comment: @NadiaCerezo you are wrong. The [documentation for `String.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-): "_yields exactly the same result as the expression `Pattern.matches(regex, str)`_". The documentation for `Pattern.matches` says it's the same as [`Matcher.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--) : "_Attempts to match the **entire region** against the pattern._" (emphasis mine). The anchors are not only redundant, but also wrong.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Ah, you're right. I've been abused by a bad tutorial (this one here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_matches.htm)... I'll fix it.
Though I must say, you could have explained it earlier instead of just saying you would downvote...

Comment: @NadiaCerezo I didn't downvote, I removed my upvote.

Comment: @BoristheSpider and I do not care what you do with your votes. I would rather have liked you to explain my mistake to me instead of just saying "You're wrong." ^^

Comment: @BoristheSpider Rereading it again, I think I misread the first example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124299/discussion-between-nadia-cerezo-and-boris-the-spider).