# How to combine multiple regular expression in java?

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to parse some log message using regular expression to find user ID, Source MAC, Source IP, Source Port etc. I am able to parse my necessary data using 3 different Regular expression.  But I am unable to combine them in a single.

I have found this question and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12858389/4542608) where he suggested to use`|`between expression, but using `|`gives the value of the first expression only, value of expression after `|`shows `null`

**My Code:**

```
 public class LogParser {



    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here        
        String mydata = "firewall,info Rural: forward: in:<pppoe-Abrar> out:wan_2, src-mac c0:4a:00:b4:7a:71, proto TCP (ACK), 192.168.4.254:51409->216.58.221.202:443, NAT (192.168.4.254:51409->192.168.43.211:51409)->216.58.221.202:443, len 52";

        pattern = Pattern.compile("<(.*?)>|src-mac(.*?), proto (.*?),|NAT \\((.*?):(.*?)->(.*?):(.*?)\\)->(.*?):(.*?),");
        matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println(matcher.groupCount());
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(3));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(4));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(5));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(6));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(7));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(8));
            System.out.println(matcher.group(9));
        }
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
9
pppoe-Abrar
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
null
```

Comment: If you have three expressions a, b, c and you concatenate them using a|b|c, the matcher will stop when it sees any one of them, without looking at the others.  If you concatenate them with (a)?(b)?(c)? then it will attempt to match all three (but notice the group numbers will change, since there are extra ())...

Comment: This helped a bit, matcher now matches till the end. But it doesn't stop until it finds the starting of the next expression. As example i was trying to find the pppoe-Abrar and then the src-mac address, but it shows pppoe-Abrar> out:wan_2, instead of pppoe-Abrar. can you help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your pattern to make this work.

Try this:

```
package testPkg;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class LogParser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String mydata = "firewall,info Rural: forward: in:<pppoe-Abrar> out:wan_2, src-mac c0:4a:00:b4:7a:71, proto TCP (ACK), 192.168.4.254:51409->216.58.221.202:443, NAT (192.168.4.254:51409->192.168.43.211:51409)->216.58.221.202:443, len 52";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("firewall,info Rural: forward: in:<(.*?)> out:wan_2, src-mac (.*?), proto (.*?), (.*?)->(.*?), NAT \\((.*?)->(.*?)\\)->(.*?), len (.*?)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(mydata);
        if (matcher.find())
        {
            System.out.println("Total number of groups macthed: " + matcher.groupCount());
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println(matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
9
pppoe-Abrar
c0:4a:00:b4:7a:71
TCP (ACK)
192.168.4.254:51409
216.58.221.202:443
192.168.4.254:51409
192.168.43.211:51409
216.58.221.202:443
52
```

Comment: I was just being fool. But, thanks you have showed me the right way. I was thinking I could escape pursing some repeating values by joining multiple regex. But actually that could cost me more computational load than  a large single one.

Comment: @S.Ahsan you may select this as answer if this helped :)

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
groovy:000> myData = "firewall,info Rural: forward: in:<pppoe-Abrar> out:wan_2, src-mac c0:4a:00:b4:7a:71, proto TCP (ACK), 192.168.4.254:51409->216.58.221.202:443, NAT (192.168.4.254:51409->192.168.43.211:51409)->216.58.221.202:443, len 52"
groovy:000> regexp = "(<([\\w-]+)>).*?(src-mac ([\\w:]+), proto ([^,]+),).*?(NAT \\(([\\d:.]+)->([\\d:.]+)\\)->([\\d.:]+))"
groovy:000> pattern = java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(regexp);
groovy:000> matcher = pattern.matcher(myData)
groovy:000> matcher.find()
===> true
groovy:000> for (int i=1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) { print matcher.group(i) + "\n"; }
<pppoe-Abrar>
pppoe-Abrar
src-mac c0:4a:00:b4:7a:71, proto TCP (ACK),
c0:4a:00:b4:7a:71
TCP (ACK)
NAT (192.168.4.254:51409->192.168.43.211:51409)->216.58.221.202:443
192.168.4.254:51409
192.168.43.211:51409
216.58.221.202:443
===> null
```